# How do I set up Ninject with ASP.NET 3.5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5, moq, ninject

I want to use Ninject to use in a **non MVC** ASP.NET 3.5 web application.

Can someone write please what do I need to download from [ninject home site](http://ninject.org) and what steps I need to take (what ddls I need to reference etc.)? I also want to use Moq objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link has a tutorial on getting set up and is up to date: [Ninject – Getting Started, Resources, Basic Binding](http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/03/23/NinjectGettingStartedResourcesBasicBinding.aspx).

Basically it says to download the build for .Net 3.5 and then to include a reference to the Ninject.dll in your project.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer.I will take a look.
Are there any other (adittional) dlls I will need ?

Comment: What about Ninject.Web.dll ? etc 
[Please see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346918/using-ninject-2-0-with-asp-net-3-5)

Comment: Shouldn't need those other dll's if you're using the 2.0 version on .Net 3.5. It was simplified to not require a myriad of dll's.

Comment: On further review that DLL may come from an extension project to help integrate Ninject with ASP.Net Webforms which is what you want to do.  It's at the following URL: http://github.com/idavis/ninject.web